# Using the Event Name Badge feature

Tags: civievent

A client of ours wants to have badges that have 2 fields on one line and would also like to have the state be the full name vs the abbreviation.  I'm pretty certain it would require custom code but posting here to be sure I haven't overlooked anything.

We are using 4.6.4 with this client.  And Drupal latest.

Comment: Hi - you might want to edit your question to include your version of Civi... you're probably not on a very old version of Civi (before the ability to edit name badges in the interface) but it would help folks out to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

As of Civi 4.4, you can configure label formats as shown here: http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/events/event-badges/

But yes, this means each field needs to be on a separate line.

In terms of having the full name for the state, Name and Mailing labels show the state/province name as the abbreviation rather than the full state/province name. This has been reported on v4.5.2, but may need patching until it is fixed in v4.8:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15505

If you want to patch it yourself for now, here's what I do.
In CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php, line 5533 (or thereabouts) is as follows:

```
    $dao->$value['pseudoField'] = $dao->$key = CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::stateProvinceAbbreviation($val);
```

Change this line to:

```
    $dao->$value['pseudoField'] = $dao->$key = CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::stateProvince($val);
```